# folderPicker using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, directory

Iam trying to open a directory(folder) in android using intent, it should look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGqXI.jpg).
But mine looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Cdu.jpg). I search on stackoverflow, google, etc.. for different methods, mime types but I didn't found anything helpful.

**This is my activity code `MainActivity.java`**

**Note: this code is not important but for you to know my method.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
    public final int REQ_CD_FILEPICKER = 101;
    
    private String input = "";
    
    private Button button;
    private TextView textview1;
    
    private Intent filePicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1000);
            } else {
                
            }
        }

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textview1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        filePicker.setType("*/*");
        filePicker.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                startActivityForResult(filePicker, REQ_CD_FILEPICKER);
            }
        });
    }
        @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
        super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);
        
        switch (_requestCode) {
            case REQ_CD_FILEPICKER:
            if (_resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> _filePath = new ArrayList<>();
                if (_data != null) {
                    if (_data.getClipData() != null) {
                        for (int _index = 0; _index < _data.getClipData().getItemCount(); _index++) {
                            ClipData.Item _item = _data.getClipData().getItemAt(_index);
                            _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _item.getUri()));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        _filePath.add(FileUtil.convertUriToFilePath(getApplicationContext(), _data.getData()));
                    }
                }
                input = _filePath.get((int)(0));
            }
            else {
                
            }
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, not `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Invalid intent operation: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE typ=*/* (has extras) }

Comment: There is no MIME type for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.